# segfault while sending buffer pointer as pass-by-value to a function, inside which reallocate happens on that buffer

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, malloc

If I have the following code, where I allocate my memory in the main function and then pass it to a function, which fills it for me like this:

```
main()
{
    char *bar = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));

    while(1)
    {
        foo(bar);
        free(bar);
        bar = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    }
}

foo(char *bar)
{
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        bar[i++] = c;
        bar = (char*) realloc(bar, sizeof(char) * (i+1));
    }
}
```

I get a segfault after a few inputs. If I do this however:

```
main()
{
    char *bar;

    while(1)
    {
        bar = foo();
        free(bar);
    }
}

char *foo()
{
    char *bar = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        bar[i++] = c;
        bar = (char*) realloc(bar, sizeof(char) * (i+1));
    }

    return bar;
}
```

, i.e. put the memory allocation to the function, everything seems to work fine. Why is that?

Comment: side note: You shouldn't assign the same pointer that you pass into `realloc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite expected behaviour. realloc() may or may not "move" the pointer you pass into it to a new address. If that happens, it also free()'s the original address. Since C is pass-by-value and not pass-by-reference, the `bar` pointer in your main() function will still refer to the old address, and you'll effectively do a double free (and the realloc()'d pointer will be lost).

Answer (score 2):

C is a pass-by-value language.  Your modifications to `bar` inside `foo()` don't affect the `bar` outside that function call.  To do what you're trying to do, you need to change that parameter to be `char **bar` and use it as `*bar` inside of `foo()`.

A couple of editorial notes:

1. You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` or `realloc()` in C.
2. Don't assign to the same pointer you pass into `realloc()`.  If it fails, you'll get a memory leak.
3. `sizeof(char)` is `1`, why bother with the extra typing?

Answer (score 0):

You could be freeing memory twice in the first case. The `realloc` call can hand you back another chunk of memory, in which case the first chunk (the one malloced in main) is freed.

Answer (score 0):

`realloc` will not always expand the same memory. Sometime it will allocate new chunk of memory if expansion is not possible.

```
main()
{
    char *bar = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));

    while(1)
    {
        foo(&bar);
        free(bar);
        bar = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    }
}

foo(char **dbar)
{
    char *bar = *dbar;
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        bar[i++] = c;
        bar = (char*) realloc(bar, sizeof(char) * (i+1));
    }
    *dbar = bar;
}
```